# How to increase the hits in algolia using PHP?

Tags: php, algolia

How can I get more then 1000 result using algolia. This function is only returning 1000 results. I have increase the page number using $currentpage++. But after returning 1000 results it is showing 0 result when there is 9000+ records in Algolia. I have written this code in php and couldn't find the possible solutions.

```
function getAlgoliaResults($index, $query, $userid, $ipaddress)
{
    global $ObjectidsArray;
    $currentpage = 0;
    $objects = null;
    $idarray = array();

    do {
        
        $objects = $index->search($query, [
            'hitsPerPage' => 1000,
            'page' => $currentpage,
            'offset' => 0,
            'length' => 1000,
            'X-Forwarded-For' => $ipaddress,
            'userToken' => $userid
        ]);

        foreach ($objects['hits'] as $rec) {
            $ObjectidsArray[$rec['id']] = $rec['objectID'];
            array_push($idarray, $rec['id']);
        }

        if (count($objects['hits']) <= 1000){

        $currentpage++;

        }
    } while (count($objects['hits']) > 0);

    return $idarray;
}
```

Comment: You increase the currentpage only if you have <= 1000 hits.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: You can try to change <= 1000, with >= 1000.

Comment: Tried that! But not working. Loop is running only one time

Comment: You set the `length` to 1000. Remove that. And for currentPage put the condition that I write above as > 1000.

Comment: So, do you solved it?

Comment: No , it didn't work.

Comment: What do you want to do, scrape some website with algolia or just configure your own algolia?

Comment: @MeT This scrtpt is currently returning 1000 data in one page and then the loop is breaking even I remove the length. So what I need is that it will return 1000 data at first page , then the page number will increase then it will again return the next 1000 data in 2nd page and the loop will continue .. But after the first 1000 data it is returning 0 data in 2nd page

Comment: @Sarkar Can you add the whole code which we can copy and reproduce.

Comment: @Sarkar, did you changed the condition to `> 1000`?